# how to display JSON values on html page using Angular 4

Tags: json, angular, aem

I have a requirement to write the JSON response values on html page. I am able to make post api call and get json response in console.
But unable to display them in web page using Angular 4.

Kindly provide any pointers.

Sample console.log display code:

```
this.http.get('src/data/data.json').subscribe(
        (data)=> console.log(data));
```

Comment: show the html code

Comment: did you try {{ jsonObject | json }}

Answer (score 0):

just bind the data to a variable and display it in the html using the json pipe. If this doesn't mean anything to you then you haven't even taken the trouble to search on google.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via angular's json pipe

```
{{ data | json }}
```

Also, if you want to format it on HTML page as well, you can use a `<pre>` tag.

Like this:

```
<pre>{{ data | json }}</pre>
```